# Number of perfect squares over $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the number of non-zero elements in $\mathbb Z_p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, which are squares, i.e., of the form $m^2$, $m \in \mathbb Z_p, m\neq 0$.

Comment: **Hint**: consider the size of the kernel of the surjection $({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z})^\times\to\big(({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z})^\times\big)^2$ which sends $x$ to $x^2$.

Comment: **Hint:** For each non-zero $m \in \mathbb Z_p$, $m^2$ is such an element. So, counting duplicates, there are $p-1$ of them. To count the duplicates, note that $m$ and $n$ have the same square mod $p$  if and only if $m^2 - n^2 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } p$. Then factorise.

Answer (score 1):

Another name for the type of elements you're asking is a *quadratic residue modulo $p$.*  Anon's hint is good for finding the size of the set of these.  Another is to look at $0\not=m^2\equiv x \pmod p$ and note that since $p$ is prime every element has a unique inverse in the unit group $\mathbb{Z}_p^\star$.  (Of course, these are only aesthetically different - the content of the proof is the same.)